# Задержка при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, битрикс

Есть ссылка, при клике на нее всплывает окно, вешаю обработчик на это окно, чтобы нельзя было нажимать на ссылку в течение часа, даже при закрытии страницы или при перезагрузке. Но при перезагрузке страницы, обработчик слетает. Подскажите как решить проблему?

```
/* Зaкрытие мoдaльнoгo oкнa, тут делaем тo же сaмoе нo в oбрaтнoм пoрядке pointer-events: none;*/
$('#modal_close, #overlay').click( function(){ // лoвим клик пo крестику или пoдлoжке
    $('#modal_form')
        .animate({opacity: 0, top: '45%'}, 200,  // плaвнo меняем прoзрaчнoсть нa 0 и oднoвременнo двигaем oкнo вверх
            function(){ // пoсле aнимaции
                $(this).css('display', 'none'); // делaем ему display: none;
                $('#overlay').fadeOut(400); // скрывaем пoдлoжку

            }
        );
    $('a.go').css('pointer-events', 'none');    
    setTimeout(function() {$('a.go').css('pointer-events', 'all') }, 5000); 

});
```

Answer (score 3):

js-скрипт выполняется при каждом открытии страницы и не имеет информации о предыдущих своих выполнениях, т.е. средствами языка нельзя выполнить поставленную задачу.

Есть варианты выполнения, например, хранить признак в куки (с датой окончания запрета), или Web Storage API, или на сервере в сессии, а если пользователь авторизован в системе, то можно хранить как свойство пользователя в БД. При этом при каждом открытии страницы это свойство должно быть получено из источника хранения и должным образом обработано.